# Select options not aligned in iOS

Tags: html, css, safari

The options of my select, in iOS (Safari), are not aligned with the parent selectbox as per Chrome or FF:
[iOS select options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YefHc.png)

I tested several other sites on Browserstack and they all have this behaviour.

Is it possible do style it in order to match Chrome/FF on Windows like this [Windows select options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrdvV.png)

I've only applied this on my select

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
```